# Iterator equivalent to null pointer?

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

In an algorithm I'm currently implementing, I need to manipulate a std::list of struct T.
T holds a reference to another instance of T, but this reference can also be "unassigned".
At first, I wanted to use a pointer to hold this reference, but using an iterator instead makes it easier to remove from the list.

My question is : how to represent the equivalent to null pointer with my iterator?

I read general solution is to use myList.end(), but in my case, I need to test whether the iterator is "null" or not, and I may add or remove elements to the list between the moment when I store the iterator and the moment I remove it from list... Should I make the iterator point to a known list containing the "null" element? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [this](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/insert/) (emphasis by me):

> Compared to the other base sequence
>   containers (vector and deque), lists
>   are the most efficient container doing
>   insertions at some position other than
>   the beginning or the end of the
>   sequence, and, unlike in these, **all of
>   the previously obtained iterators and
>   references remain valid after the
>   insertion and refer to the same
>   elements they were referring before.**

The same applies to erasure (with the obvious exception of iterators referring to a deleted element becoming invalidated). So yes, obtaining `end()` will always point to the same "invalid" element and should be safe to use.

Comment: Ok, great! I had a feeling that end() would be an "exception to the rule", and that it would represent the next element you would push_back on your list...

Comment: Nah, the STL is smarter than that. :)

Comment: I'm curious: does anyone know if that is in 'the standard' as well?

Comment: @sje397: 23.2.2.3.1 and onwards in [this version](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf)